# Вызывает ли ::class подгрузку класса?

Tags: php

Часто бывает необходимо в разных конфигах писать название класса (с пространствами имен). Видел по разному пишут: например просто строкой `'\MyNamespace\MyClass'`, или `MyClass::class`. Правда для последнего варианта еще `use` придется написать, ну или полное имя опять же с неймспейсами. Еще в `Yii` раньше был способ с их собственным методом `className()` который сейчас уже объявлен *deprecated*, но речь не о нем.

В способе `MyClass::class` есть один плюс по сравнению с первым - удобство рефакторинга (ну и автокомплит тоже). Т.е. если я изменю ему имя или неймспейс то IDE сама заменит его в месте использования таким образом, а вот в строке вряд-ли (да даже ошибку не отобразит).

Интересует не вызывает ли такое использование каких-то дополнительных накладных расходов вроде подгрузки класса в этом месте (или когда я `use` пишу)?

Comment: а как вы хотите обратится к константе класса `MyClass::class` не загружая его?

Comment: @teran к какой константе? Вы о чем вообще?

Comment: @teran `class` это константа? Я думал это какая-то особая php-шная магия :D

Comment: @teran я все-таки нашел [это](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) сам. Я таки был прав - это не просто константа. Это все-таки магия! :D И судя по всему она таки не вызывает загрузку класса. А вот насчет `use` я не уверен.

Comment: Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name of the ClassName class by using ClassName::class. 

The class name resolution using ::class is a compile time transformation. That means at the time the class name string is created no autoloading has happened yet. As a consequence, class names are expanded even if the class does not exist. No error is issued in that case.

Comment: магия не меняет того, что это константа: _"Начиная с PHP 5.5.0 доступна специальная константа ::class, которой на этапе компиляции присваивается полное имя класса."_ ([линк](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.constants.php)) . Речь идет о том, что это константа и для каждого класса она определяется/назначается автоматически при компиляции. То есть считай дописывается к коду. Что в вашей цитате собственно подтверждается. А вот предпоследнее предложение вашей цитаты не совсем ясно.

Comment: @teran цитата верная, php файл может быть совсем пустой даже без неймспейса, и даже хуже - его может не существовать вовсе, тем не менее вызов MyClass::class  с use или без use отработает корректно, т.е. никаких накладных расходов нет

Comment: @DarkByte ходит ещё ошибочное мнение, что лучше писать строку если класс используется всего в одном методе класса например, однако весь огород use между неймспейсом и классом работает лишь как маппер и используется только при необходимости, php когда натыкается на вызов метода/свойства класса сначала пытается найти его в use, если там не нашёл - пытается найти в текущем неймпейсе, если и там нет - ошибка, повторюсь что при вызове константы ::class ошибки не будет, так как файл совершенно не затрагивается

Comment: @Blacknife о том и речь, как класса может не быть. Исходя из этого, `::class` это не константа внутри класса, а в целом `XXX::class` становится константой, независимой, причем подставляемой на этапе компиляции в код. Фактически даже выходит, что это языковая конструкция подменяемая во время компиляции. хз почему тогда это константой называют в документации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Директивы `use` не существуют в runtime вовсе. Они обрабатывается на этапе компиляции и соответственно никак не могут вызывать автозагрузку классов, которая как раз runtime.

Так называемые [магические константы](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) совершенно так же обрабатываются уже на этапе компиляции:

> All these "magical" constants are resolved at compile time

И на этапе компиляции у вас ещё нет автозагрузки классов, её вы активируете позже на этапе выполнения через `spl_autoload_register` или объявлением функции `__autoload` (устаревший способ).

Comment: Я не силен во внутренностях php. Объясните пожалуйста что вы подразумеваете под компиляцией? Ведь php - интерпретируемый язык! Наверное он как и питон компилируется в какой-нибудь промежуточный байт-код для ускорения?

Comment: @DarkByte именно это и подразумевают